# Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal hangs indefinitely

Tags: android, wear-os, google-fit

I am writing an Android Wear application.  I am trying to query the step delta and whenever I do, readDailyTotal hangs indefinitely.  I've tried this on an emulator and on a physical device with no luck.

Here is the code that I use to connect the client (I am loading local data to the device):

```
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .useDefaultAccount()
      .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
      .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .build();
    mClient.connect();
```

I subscribe to the recording API with:

```
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .setResultCallback( /* some stuff */);
```

Finally, I query the data in an AsyncTask (and where it hangs) with:

```
    PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
```

I've run through the debugger and have isolated the hanging to that line.

Any ideas would be appreciated because I've been scratching my head and searching for a few days now.

Comment: Does your `GoogleApiClient` actually connect?

Comment: I did verify that it connects.  It called onConnect in my ConnectionCallback.

Comment: I should add that this is when I instantiate the AsyncTask.

Comment: Why are you calling `readDailyTotal` in an `AsyncTask`? It is already an async operation (that's why it returns a `PendingResult`)

Comment: I pulled it from an example.  After your questioning my irrational logic, I moved it out of the AsyncTask to a method and it returns now.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readDailyTotal` does not need to be called within `AsyncTask` as it is already an async operation (that's why it returns a `PendingResult`).